# How to use current Appium server without reinitializing new server

Tags: appium

I create Appium server like so

```
AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
builder.withIPAddress(ipAddress);
builder.usingPort(port);
builder.withArgument(flag, flagValue);
AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
```

But I wonder how can I use a currently running Appium server without creating a new one?

Can I use the same session? I want to reinitialize as little as possible from one test to the next.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I check to see if the server is already running external to the script with the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

int port = 4723;

public boolean serverIsRunnning() {

    boolean isServerRunning = false;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // If control comes here, then it means that the port is in use
        isServerRunning = true;
    } finally {
        serverSocket = null;
    }

    return isServerRunning;

}
```

It merely checks to see if the port is in use.

If it is running, then when you initialize the driver, you need to hard code the URL as "http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub" or whatever your external server settings are.  Otherwise I use the `service.getUrl();` returned by my server starter class, which is generally the same thing as the default setting for the external starter.

Comment: This code may also catch if a port is blocked because another socket is connect right?

Comment: It will only check the port you specify, and I just realized that the code as shown above will not work because it's only a portion of the class - the "port" variable is defined as a class variable and I forgot to include that.  It's hard-coded to 4723 in my class, but you could make the port a parameter if you want.  But yes, since it's using the new keyword, it will get trapped as "in use" only for the port checked.  So, pass to it the port you might be using externally, which in my case is the same port as internally.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer by adding that line of code to make it clearer for others.

Comment: I think the method could be renamed to portInUse. If the port is not in use, the server could still be running, so the method would return a false positive.

Comment: You can call it whatever you want, I'm using that name because Appium specifically recommends using port 4723 and that's the port it checks.  If you're not using port 4723 when you launch it manually, then simply change it to whatever port you would have launched it on.  I don't understand what part you're not getting.  This works, I use it myself.  Sometimes I start Appium BEFORE a test, sometimes I let the test start it, both work fine.

Comment: What I mean is if the port is not in use, the method will return false if it connects to the server, won't it?

Comment: While the server is running, the port is open, whether it is active or not, it is reserved and it is not released until the server is stopped.